# Parse html text with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I wanted to parse the money of a sky block account today in python, but I couldn't get it to work.
The website is https://sky.lea.moe/stats/LeaPhant/.

The html tag is:

```
<span class="stat-value">$0.08</span>
```

This is my current code:

```
from requests_futures import sessions
skyblock = open("skyblock_profile.txt", "w+")
file = open("names.txt", "r")
session = sessions.FuturesSession(max_workers=1000)
check = [s.rstrip() for s in file.readlines()]
for lines in check:
    r = session.get(f"https://sky.lea.moe/stats/{lines}")
    response = r.result()
    if "No user with the" in response.text or "Player has no" in response.text:
        print(f"{lines}: False")
    else:
       print(f"{lines}: True")
       skyblock.write(f"{lines}: Skyblock Profile: True\n")
```

I have heard of bs4 before but I dont know how to use it in this situation, it would be really nice if someone could help me with this, thanks!

Comment: first find some tutorial or read [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the text like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

[YOUR CODE TO GET THE RESPONSE FROM THE PAGE]

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")  
desired_tag = soup.find("span", {"class": "stat-value"}) # this gets the desired tag
print(desired_tag.text)  # this gets you the text in the HTML tag, i.e. "$0.08"
```

If you want to find all of the HTML span tags with the desired tag, you can use `soup.find_all()` instead of `soup.find()`, and it'll return a list of all the tags that match.